# Auto refresh DataTables table with reloading the whole page

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Is anyone able to guide on how to refresh datatables datas in every 1min interval without reloading the entire page.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
           var refreshTable = $('#id_css').DataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/alert_data.txt',
                "bServerSide": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 100,
                "bFilter": false,
                "aaSorting" : [[2, "desc"]],
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                    if ( aData[2] == "5" )
                    {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                    }
                    else if ( aData[2] == "4" )
                    {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                    }
                 }

              });
setInterval (function test() {
refreshTable.fnDraw();
}, 1000);
 });
```

I have tried using this plugin **fnReloadAjax.js** but keep getting **TypeError: refreshTable.fnReloadAjax is not a function**. This is how I used it:

```
setInterval (function test() {
refreshTable.fnReloadAjax();
}, 1000);
```

and i have also added its cdn

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/api/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>
```

Any assistance or guide will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its strange that changing the **DataTable** to **dataTable** was the root cause of this failing the whole time. That is small d instead of capital D, really annoying...

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       var refreshTable = $('#id_css').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/alert_data.txt',
```

Comment: The reason is that [JavaScript is Case Sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity).

Comment: This explanation is on the DataTables web-site: "It is important to note the difference between $( selector ).DataTable() and $( selector ).dataTable(). The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object. An api() method is added to the jQuery object so you can easily access the API, but the jQuery object can be useful for manipulating the table node, as you would with any other jQuery instance (such as using addClass(), etc.)."

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var refreshTable = $('#id_css').DataTable({ ...
```

Then within the document.ready function (has to be in the scope otherwise fnDraw won't work) you use:

```
setInterval (function test() {
    refreshTable.fnDraw();
}, 1000);
```

There is a scope issue, the code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       var refreshTable = $('#id_css').DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/alert_data.txt',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaSorting" : [[2, "desc"]],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if ( aData[2] == "5" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                }
                else if ( aData[2] == "4" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                }
             }   
       });
       setInterval (function test() {
         refreshTable.fnDraw();
       }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: Move the setInterval inbetween your 2nd last }); and last });

Comment: sorry that was a typo, its inbetween the 2 });

Comment: I have seen your changes but still having same error

Comment: OK thanks for your effort but its strange while a simple change fixed it. I have resolved it now.

Comment: That's weird because the setInterval does work on jsfiddle and the scope is sorted out. Have you tried it like that without the AjaxReload plugin?