# Datatable autorefresh is changing the CSS of the Table

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, refresh

I have this
table.php

```js
<?php 
 $connect = mysqli_connect("dbexample.com", "dboexample", "password", "dbexample"); 
 $query ="SELECT * FROM te_lb_load_board, te_lb_load_board_cstm WHERE te_lb_load_board.id = te_lb_load_board_cstm.id_c AND te_lb_load_board_cstm.load_status_c LIKE '%open%' ORDER BY shipping_date_c DESC, shipping_time_c ASC"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
 ?> 
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
      <head> 
           <title>Load Board</title> 
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>      
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#employee_data').DataTable(); 
 }); 
 setInterval(function () {
      table.fnReloadAjax();
}, 3000);
 </script> 
      </head> 
      <body> 
           <br /><br /> 
           <div class="container"> 
                <h3 align="center">Load Board</h3> 
                <br /> 
                <div class="table-responsive"> 
                     <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered"> 
                          <thead> 
                               <tr>   
                                    <td>Date</td> 
                                    <td>Time</td>
                                    <td>Zip</td> 
                                    <td>City</td> 
                                    <td>Country</td> 
                                    <td>Date</td>
                                    <td>Time</td>
                                    <td>Zip</td>
                                    <td>City</td>
                                    <td>Country</td>
                                    <td>Description</td>
                               </tr> 
                          </thead> 
                          <?php 
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                          { 
                               echo ' 
                               <tr>   
                                    <td>'.$row['shipping_date_c'].'</td> 
                                    <td>'.$row['shipping_time_c'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["billing_address_postalcode"].'</td> 
                                    <td>'.$row["billing_address_city"].'</td> 
                                    <td>'.$row["billing_address_country"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['arrival_date_c'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row['arrival_time_c'].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["shipping_address_postalcode"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["shipping_address_city"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["shipping_address_country"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["description"].'</td> 
                               </tr> 
                               '; 
                          } 
                          ?> 
                     </table> 
                </div> 
           </div> 
      </body> 
  
 </html>
```

I create an index.php file with this code:

```js
<title>Glastopf Observation Center</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('table.php'); // table.php is where I have my table
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>
 
<div id="results">Loading data ...</div>
```

It is working, I got the autrefresh of my data on the table but I have every 3 seconds this css problem:

[This is how it looks as usual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUz7P.jpg)

[This is how it looks after 3 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO24I.jpg)

I put the css links into the index.php file I mentioned before but I still have the same css problems:

```js
<title>Glastopf Observation Center</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>      
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
 
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('table.php');
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>
 
<div id="results">Loading data ...</div>
```

Comment: In my case I manually `addClass` via jQuery after loading of the table; ex: `$('#table_filter div').addClass('input-field col s12');` . You just have to find the right element via developer mode.

Comment: Hi juntapao, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Could you please provide an example I can use in my case? Thanks

Comment: would you create a fiddle?

Comment: I would only get my table updating data automatically ater few seconds I put the Data inside my Database Mysql.

Comment: Hi juntapao, are you suggesting me somenthing like in this Topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282610/auto-refresh-datatables-table-with-reloading-the-whole-page

Answer (score 0):

I got it working...

In your table.php (you have to use PDO instead of MySQLi):

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbexample;host=dbexample.com;port=3306", "dboexample", "password");
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM te_lb_load_board, te_lb_load_board_cstm WHERE te_lb_load_board.id = te_lb_load_board_cstm.id_c AND te_lb_load_board_cstm.load_status_c LIKE '%open%' ORDER BY shipping_date_c DESC, shipping_time_c ASC");
$query->execute();
echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());
?>
```

In your index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Load Board</title> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
</head> 
<body> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <h3 align="center">Load Board</h3> 
        <br /> 
        <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table;
            $.post('table.php', {}, function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    table = $('#employee_data').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                             {'data': 'shipping_date_c', 'title': 'Date'}
                            ,{'data': 'shipping_time_c', 'title': 'Time'}
                            ,{'data': 'billing_address_postalcode', 'title': 'Zip'}
                            ,{'data': 'billing_address_city', 'title': 'City'}
                            ,{'data': 'billing_address_country', 'title': 'Country'}
                            ,{'data': 'arrival_date_c', 'title': 'Date'}
                            ,{'data': 'arrival_time_c', 'title': 'Time'}
                            ,{'data': 'shipping_address_postalcode', 'title': 'Zip'}
                            ,{'data': 'shipping_address_city', 'title': 'City'}
                            ,{'data': 'shipping_address_country', 'title': 'Country'}
                            ,{'data': 'description', 'title': 'Description'}
                        ]
                    }); 
                }
            }, 'json');
            setInterval(function () {
                table.clear().draw();
                $.post('table.php', {}, function(data) {
                    table.rows.add(data).draw();
                }, 'json');
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```